# What is the gradient?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I searched for similar questions, and apparently they were either too advanced, or too basic. But I couldn't find exactly what I am looking for.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that takes $n$-many real numbers as its input, and maps each such input to a real number.

Also, for any $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, let $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x_i} = g_i$ be the indefinite derivative of function $f$ when varying the $i^{th}$, and holding all other inputs constant.

Then, I call $(g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n)$ the "gradient function of function $f$".

- **Question 1.** Is "gradient function" a suitable name? Maybe "indefinite gradient"? Any better name out there?

For any input $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\big(g_1(x_1),g_2(x_2),\ldots,g_n(x_n)\big)$ is the gradient of function $f$ at point $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

- **Question 2.** Is $\big(g_1(x_1),g_2(x_2),\ldots,g_n(x_n)\big)$ really the gradient of $f$ at point $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$? Do I need to do something extra in order to make it really the gradient? Perhaps, some kind of aggregation of the numbers $g_1(x_1)$, $g_2(x_2)$, $\ldots$, $g_n(x_n)$ in order to produce an $n$-dimensional vector that, finally, qualifies as the gradient of $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$?

### Question 2 expanded:

I can see how $g_i$ is the indefinite derivative of function $f$ if we assume that all inputs other than $x_i$ are constant, while only $x_i$ is variable. But I'm stuck at understanding whether simply the individual slopes/derivatives $g_i(x_i)$ will make a gradient vector $\big(g_1(x_1),g_2(x_2),\ldots,g_n(x_n)\big)$.

For example, suppose that we have a 3-dimensional shape. The gradient at some point can be represented as a needle that rests at the point (e.g. some kind of 3-dimensional tangent). This needle will have some direction in the 3-dimensional space. But is the direction of this needle, also the direction of $\big(g_1(x_1),g_2(x_2),\ldots,g_n(x_n)\big)$?

Comment: Start with a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. The gradient of $f$ is actually a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is orthogonal (i.e. normal) to the level sets of $f$. It points in the direction of maximal increase of $f$, and its norm tells you how fast $f$ is increasing in that direction. Its formula is standard, and you can find it in many books/lecture notes. I hope this helps.

Comment: Is the gradient a *vector field*? Or is it a *single vector in a vector field*?

Comment: You can talk about the gradient of a function $f$ at a point, that's a vector (better to think of it as an element in the cotangent space at that point, but this is more advanced). As you vary the basepoint, you get a vector field.

Comment: Thank you. Before I move forward, any idea what's the appropriate naming for these 2 distinct things? Is it just "gradient of a function at a point" and "gradient of a function at all points"? Less mouthful names?

Comment: You can call the vector field notion the gradient of $f$, and if it is at a point $p$, you can say the gradient of $f$ at $p$. You can also write them as $\nabla(f)$ and $\nabla(f)_p$ respectively. $\nabla$ is a more or less standard notation for the gradient.

Comment: Why not $\nabla\big(f(p)\big)$ instead of $\nabla(f)_p$?

Comment: well, it is similar to the derivative of $f$ at $x$, which is denoted by $f'(x)$, and not $f(x)'$.

Comment: Oh got it. $f(p)$ is a number. Taking the gradient of a number is trivial and not what I'm doing here.

Comment: Since the gradient is some kind of a multi-dimensional derivative, and since the derivative of function $f$ at point $p$ is named $f'(p)$, I think its gradient variant should be $f^{\nabla}(p)$. Thoughts?